# Nested tree structure collapse not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview

In this tree structure when i clicked parent node, parent node only should collapse but here all child node are collapse. Its should be happen one by one [here demo link][1]

```
  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/1lYuoypzmREOTG2sxCqh?p=preview*
```

Comment: I don't see your problem. when you click a parent node only the parent collapses. but since the children are inside the parent they are hidden. It's not possible to collapse the parent and still show the children. It wouldn't make sense. Am I not understanding your issue?

Comment: Collapse should be happen one by one.